# Neural architecture search for yolo like object detectors

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am trying to do NAS for object detectors, this is the architecture developed for it, the idea is to encode bitstrings to introduce skips connection inside the phases of the architecture and feed it to the genetic algorithms.

But first i wanted to verify the architecture and all nodes are sequentially connected, but when i train by taking a sample picture and applying yolo principle of box loss between predicted bbox in grid where the centre of gtruth lies and gtruth, the model loss remain constant and model output also, most of the time model outputs bbox as zeroes as i have applied relu.

any help/advice?

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import MaxPool2d
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F

class oneNode(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self,inchannels,outchannels):
       super(oneNode,self).__init__()
       self.conv = nn.Conv2d(inchannels,outchannels,kernel_size=3,padding=1)
       self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(outchannels)
       self.relu = nn.ReLU()
     def forward(self,x):
        out = self.conv(x)
        out = self.bn(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        return out
                  
class Architecture(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_channels,out_channels):
        super(Architecture,self).__init__()

        #phase1
        self.phase1_1 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase1_2 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase1_3 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase1_4 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase1_5 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase1_6 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase1_7 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)

        #max pool and conv
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels,out_channels,kernel_size=3,padding=1)
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels,out_channels,kernel_size=3,padding=1)

        #phase2
        self.phase2_1 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase2_2 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase2_3 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase2_4 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase2_5 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase2_6 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase2_7 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)

        #max pool and conv
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels,out_channels,kernel_size=3,padding=1)
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels,out_channels,kernel_size=3,padding=1)
        
        #phase3
        self.phase3_1 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase3_2 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase3_3 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase3_4 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase3_5 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase3_6 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)
        self.phase3_7 = oneNode(in_channels,out_channels)

     
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.phase1_1(x)
        out = self.phase1_2(out)
        out = self.phase1_3(out)
        out = self.phase1_4(out)
        out = self.phase1_5(out)
        out = self.phase1_6(out)
        out = self.phase1_7(out)
        out = self.conv1(out)
        out = self.maxpool1(out)
        out = self.conv2(out)

        out = self.phase2_1(out)
        out = self.phase2_2(out)
        out = self.phase2_3(out)
        out = self.phase2_4(out)
        out = self.phase2_5(out)
        out = self.phase2_6(out)
        out = self.phase2_7(out)
        out = self.conv3(out)
        out = self.maxpool2(out)
        out = self.conv4(out)

        out = self.phase3_1(out)
        out = self.phase3_2(out)
        out = self.phase3_3(out)
        out = self.phase3_4(out)
        out = self.phase3_5(out)
        out = self.phase3_6(out)
        out = self.phase3_7(out)

        return out
        
                
class objectNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, num_classes):
        super(objectNet, self).__init__()
        
        self.base_network = Architecture(in_channels, out_channels)
        
        self.flattening = nn.Flatten()
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(131072, 1024)
        
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024,7*7*12)
         
    def forward(self, x):
        
        out = self.base_network(x)
        out = self.flattening(out)
        out = self.fc1(out)    
        out = self.fc2(out)  
        out = F.relu(out)      # to force non negativity
        out = out.view(-1, 12, 7, 7)      
        return out
               
class def_node(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(def_node, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        return x        
               
class CombinedNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, num_classes):
        super(CombinedNet, self).__init__()
        
        self.default_node = def_node()
        self.object_net = objectNet(128, 128, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.default_node(x)
    
        x = self.object_net(x)
        return x
        
        
       
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

inchannels = 128
outchannels = 128
classes = 2

NASYOD = CombinedNet(inchannels,outchannels,classes) 

smooth_l1_loss = nn.SmoothL1Loss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(NASYOD.parameters(), lr=0.01)

image_path = "PERSON.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)



import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('PERSON.jpg')
labels_file = 'PERSON.txt'
GRID = []

with open(labels_file, 'r') as file:
    labels = file.readlines()


if image is None:
    print("Failed to load the image.")
else:

    rows, cols = 7, 7
    height, width, _ = image.shape
    thickness = 3


    cell_width = width // cols
    cell_height = height // rows
    CELL_NO = 1
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            thickness = 1
            cell_x1 = j * cell_width
            cell_y1 = i * cell_height
            cell_x2 = (j + 1) * cell_width
            cell_y2 = (i + 1) * cell_height

   
            cell_color = (0, 255, 0)

      
            for label in labels:
                parts = label.split()
                class_id, x_center, y_center, box_width, box_height = map(float, parts[0:5])

     
                box_center_x = int(x_center * width)
                box_center_y = int(y_center * height)
                cv2.rectangle(image, (int((x_center - box_width / 2) * width), int((y_center - box_height / 2) * height)),
                          (int((x_center + box_width / 2) * width), int((y_center + box_height / 2) * height)),
                          (0, 0, 0), 3)  # Unfilled bounding box

                cv2.circle(image, (box_center_x, box_center_y), 4, (0, 165, 255), 7)  
              
                if cell_x1 < box_center_x < cell_x2 and cell_y1 < box_center_y < cell_y2:
                    cell_color = (0, 0, 255)  # Change color to red
                    thickness = 5
                    GRID.append(CELL_NO)
                CELL_NO+=1

     
                cv2.rectangle(image, (cell_x1, cell_y1), (cell_x2, cell_y2), cell_color, thickness) 


    print(GRID)
    cv2.imshow('Preprocessor YOLO', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


image_path = "PERSON.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path)



transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((128, 128)), 
    transforms.ToTensor()           
])



def calculate_iou(x1_box1, y1_box1, width_box1, height_box1, x1_box2, y1_box2, width_box2, height_box2):

    x2_box1 = x1_box1 + width_box1
    y2_box1 = y1_box1 + height_box1
    x2_box2 = x1_box2 + width_box2
    y2_box2 = y1_box2 + height_box2


    x1_intersection = max(x1_box1, x1_box2)
    y1_intersection = max(y1_box1, y1_box2)
    x2_intersection = min(x2_box1, x2_box2)
    y2_intersection = min(y2_box1, y2_box2)


    width_intersection = max(0, x2_intersection - x1_intersection)
    height_intersection = max(0, y2_intersection - y1_intersection)


    area_box1 = width_box1 * height_box1
    area_box2 = width_box2 * height_box2
    area_intersection = width_intersection * height_intersection

 
    iou = area_intersection / (area_box1 + area_box2 - area_intersection)

    return iou

input_data = transform(image)
input_data = input_data.unsqueeze(0) 
print(input_data)           
print(input_data.shape)

num_epochs = 1000
gx,gy,gh,gw = 0.355556, 0.671070, 0.080556, 0.398943
gt_bbox = torch.tensor([gx, gy, gh, gw], dtype=torch.float32)
print(GRID[0])
BOX1 = []
BOX2 = []
LOSS = []
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = NASYOD(input_data)
    OUTPUTS = outputs.view(-1, 12)
    OUTPUTS = OUTPUTS[30].tolist()
    print("OUTPUTS",OUTPUTS)
    BOX1 = []
    BOX2 = []
    BOX1.append(OUTPUTS[:5])
    BOX2.append(OUTPUTS[5:10])
    X1,Y1,H1,W1,O1=BOX1[0][0],BOX1[0][1],BOX1[0][2],BOX1[0][3],BOX1[0][4]
    X2,Y2,H2,W2,O2=BOX2[0][0],BOX2[0][1],BOX2[0][2],BOX2[0][3],BOX2[0][4]
    print(X1,Y1,W1,H1)
    print(X2,Y2,W2,H2)
    iou1 = calculate_iou(X1,Y1,H1,W1,gx,gy,gh,gw)
    iou2 = calculate_iou(X2,Y2,W2,H2,gx,gy,gh,gw)
    print(iou1,iou2)
    if iou1>iou2:
       predicted_bbox = torch.tensor([X1,Y1,H1,W1],dtype = torch.float32,requires_grad=True)
       bbox_loss = smooth_l1_loss(predicted_bbox, gt_bbox)
    elif iou1<iou2:
       predicted_bbox = torch.tensor([X2,Y2,H2,W2],dtype = torch.float32,requires_grad=True)
       bbox_loss = smooth_l1_loss(predicted_bbox, gt_bbox)
    elif iou1==iou2:
       predicted_bbox = torch.tensor([X1,Y1,W1,H1],dtype = torch.float32,requires_grad=True)
       bbox_loss = smooth_l1_loss(predicted_bbox, gt_bbox)
    LOSS.append(bbox_loss.item())   
    bbox_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(f"Epoch:{epoch+1},bbox_loss:{bbox_loss}")  
plt.plot(LOSS,range(num_epochs)) 
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Bounding Box Loss')
plt.title('Bounding Box Loss vs. Epoch')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()   
print("Finished Training")
```